# Python library not found

Tags: bash, python-2.7, cron

After installing python 2.7.13 version can't find run python, because python library not found :

[image]

then I tried install link with following line:

```
ln -s /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/python2/libpython2.7.so.1.0 /lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
```

then try again, appears following error:

```
python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: Error 20
```

Then I reinstall all python libraries by this link: https://centos.pkgs.org/6/ius-i386/python27-libs-2.7.13-2.ius.centos6.i686.rpm.html

python via terminal works now, but then run bash script vi crontab not works, anybody know why?

Comment: which system is it? how did you install it? it doesn't look like an ordinary installation

Comment: Seems like your bash session is using one version of Python and crontab is using another, I would use "whereis" to find the path to the Python executable in your terminal session and then use the full path to the version of Python in any scripts referenced by Crontab.